# Multiple model formsets in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelformset `AddressFormSet = modelformset_factory(Address)`. In my view I assign this formset to different context variables, but they seem to be duplicated. The input names are the same.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(TravelCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['address1'] = AddressFormSet(self.request.POST)
        context['address2'] = AddressFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context['address1'] = AddressFormSet(queryset=self.model.objects.none())
        context['address2'] = AddressFormSet(queryset=self.model.objects.none())
    return context
```

How can I give them different names so data from both formsets creates objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide both Formsets with a different prefix when you create them from a factory, otherwise they will both be working with the same names from the post data

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(TravelCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['address1'] = AddressFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='address1')
        context['address2'] = AddressFormSet(self.request.POST, prefix='address2')
    else:
        context['address1'] = AddressFormSet(queryset=self.model.objects.none(), prefix='address1')
        context['address2'] = AddressFormSet(queryset=self.model.objects.none(), prefix='address2')
    return context
```

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view